# No view found for id 0x7f080000

Tags: android

I can seem to be able to get my fragment to work. There is an entry in the R file for it. Changing the id does not fix it of course. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I try to create it in the Activity. But I only get the error.

```
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for 
    id 0x7f080000 (test.jk.com.cameratest:id/relativeLayout) for
 fragment SimpleCameraIntentFragment{42749310 #0 id=0x7f080000}
```

There is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        BaseFragment targetFragment = null;

        targetFragment = SimpleCameraIntentFragment.newInstance(1);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.relativeLayout, targetFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

This is the fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take picture"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTakePicture"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewThumb"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFullSize"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonTakePicture" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  null;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

    // Set the image view
    mImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFullSize);
    mThumbnailImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewThumb);
    Button takePictureButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePicture);

    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on button clicks
    takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

public static SimpleCameraIntentFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        SimpleCameraIntentFragment fragment = new SimpleCameraIntentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am getting the fragmentManager from a specific Activity. I cannot send in the Fragment it has to be the activity's ID that is sent in.

This is the ID of the activity which is the correct way of doing it.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(**R.id.camActivity**, targetFragment)
                .commit();
```

This ID is not working since it's the ID of the fragment

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(**R.id.relativeLayout**, targetFragment)
                .commit();
```